# Add Index of 2-dimensional Array to to the end of List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, addition

I am working on a small game where the player clicks a button whichs value is from a 2-dimensional Array.[This is how the game looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeOGH.png) In case the player wants to revert his action I want to save the steps the player took in a List, and when he clicks the "revert"-button the last item of the list gets reverted. Problem is I don't know how to the save the index of a 2-dimensional Array to a list.

My code is far for the array is following

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
            counter++;
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton("" + counter);

            buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
            buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new ButtonPress());
            fenster.add(buttons[i][j]);
```

And the code for the ActionListener is here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        amountMoves++;
        moves.setText("Moves: " + amountMoves);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
                if (((JButton) e.getSource()).equals(buttons[i][j])) {
                    x = i; 
                    y = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Lists aren't my strongpoint so so far I only have this:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> steps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I know I can add a element with `steps.add()` and delete the last element with `steps.remove(steps.size() - 1);`, but that's all so far

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: With the help of @Johnny Mopp and @SSP I figured out what to do. First I created a List of the type String `ArrayList<String> steps = new ArrayList<String>();` (you can alternativly use a List of the type JButton) and add it in the Actionlister with `steps.add(buttons[i][j].getText());`

Comment: By reverted, do you mean that the last item in the List gets deleted, or that it becomes equal to the one before it?

Comment: I mean the last item of the list gets deleted

Comment: There are lots of options. You might store the actual button (`ArrayList<Button>`)? Or use an array of [`Pair`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html).....

Comment: That helped me, I figured it out, big thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a Lists of list :-

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> steps = new ArrayList<>();
```

if you get row 2 and column 2 data to be saved, Save value like below:-

```
steps.get(1).add(1{index of column},2{value to be stored});
```

If you are adding element for first time, You need to instantiate object like below:-

```
if(steps.get(1) == null){
    steps.get(1) = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Accessing data

```
 steps.get(1).get(2);
```